# Multiprocessing-backed parallel loops cannot be nested below threads warning and problem

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nested-loops, python-multithreading, cross-validation

So I have a python flask app that is currently using waitress to accept requests that start model generations. During these model generations I perform a cross_fold_validation using sklearn's cross_validate(). During this cross_validate I  have set the n_jobs args to some number other than 1 or when I set the n_jobs in the model args to something than 1, I get the following warning:

> "UserWarning: Multiprocessing-backed parallel loops cannot be nest
> below threads, setting n_jobs=1"

When the function runs. This is the exact line that is running.

```
accuracy = cross_validate(model_pipeline, content_strings, y_target_values, 
n_jobs=-4, cv=5, error_score="raise")
```

I know that the model_pipeline and all the other variables are correct because even at 1 job, the function completes, just slowly. But it completes and I get my accuracies.

So I've done some research and tried changing the thread that runs this specific bit of code. Originally using the threading library. I tried `'threading.current_thread().name = "MainThread"'` but that didn't work. So I figured I'd start a whole new thread to replace the waitress daemon thread with a main thread that is not a daemon. After doing that I'm able to run the whole generation code that I have under a thread called "MainThread" and daemon = false. But still, I receive the error.

I've also tried changing the joblib.parallel_backend to all available default options. So "loky", "multiprocessing", and "threading". Also set the context `effective_n_jobs` to=-1. But still to no avail I receive the error and the cross_validation happens with a single job.

Like is what I'm doing trying to run the cross_validation under a thread just not allowed cause it's technically nested? But if that's the case then running models in a flask service like what I'm doing would never allow them to run to their full potential. Would I have to make a separate script that is stored and ran by flask in some way that is under a main thread?

Any help or maybe explanation as to why what I'm trying isn't allowing me to run the models with multiple jobs would be appreciated.